# SQL how to exclude data using datediff and not exists in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to exclude some data in my query, but wasn't able to figure out myself after searching for keywords.

[image]

Above is the example table with columns I have with following query :

`SELECT id, date, health, state, reason FROM table1`

my goal is excluding (state = START) case and cases when (health = NO && reason = REASON1) if this occurs in 10 minutes after START happen. It's possible to have (health = NO && reason = REASON1) after 10 minutes of START event, and I want to leave them there as is if condition of in 10 minutes doesn't meet.

Below is the goal I wanted to achieve.

[image]

Excluding (state = START) was very easy :

`SELECT id, date, health, state, reason FROM table1 WHERE state not in ('START')`

but I wasn't able to figure out how to exclude (health = NO && reason = REASON1) if this occurs in 10 minutes after START happen part.

My idea was using DATEDIFF and not exists, like following :

`SELECT id, date, health, state, reason FROM table1 WHERE state not in ('START') and (health = 'NO' and reason = 'REASON1' and DATEDIFF(minute,(current_date)?,(last starting time)?) < 15)`

(current_date)?,(last starting time)? parts I'm not sure how to achieve this. I think I should use NOT EXISTS as well for the second condition, but the one I tried didn't work. Can anyone help or give me direction to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a window function to calculate the previous start date.  Then the filtering is pretty easy:

```
SELECT id, date, health, state, reason
FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             MAX(CASE WHEN state = 'START' THEN date END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) as prev_start_date
      FROM table1 t1
     ) t1
WHERE state <> 'START' OR
      (health = 'NO' AND
       reason = 'REASON1' AND
       prev_start_date > date - interval 10 minute
      );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for mentioning window function, it was very useful and I went over this during weekend. From your answer, the second condition I want to exclude still shows up in result because `state <> 'START'` shows the data I want to exclude. If I run those OR conditions separate, they are right, but when I use OR, they still show up due to second condition not being START

Comment: `SELECT id, date, health, state, reason
FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             MAX(CASE WHEN state = 'START' THEN date END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) as prev_start_date
      FROM table1 t1
     ) t1
WHERE id = '2200' AND
date between '2020-04-09 00:00:00' and '2020-04-11 23:00:00' AND
 (
       state not in ('START') OR 
       (reason = 'REASON1' AND
       extract(epoch from (date - prev_start_date)) > 60 * 10)
      );`
This is exact query I ran.